# C# SQLite 3 read text field as binary data

Tags: c#, select, sqlite, blob

In a SQLite database I have this **`fruit`** table:

```
CREATE TABLE "fruit"
(
    "fruit_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "fruit_name" TEXT,
    "data" TEXT,
    "ex_data" BLOB
)
```

Now I want to loop **every rows** and get the **`data`** field as `byte[]` data:

```
string stm = "SELECT * FROM fruit";

using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, conn))
{
    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr["fruit_name"] as string == "banana")
            {
                var ex_data = (byte[])rdr["ex_data"];
                var data = (byte[])rdr["data"];        // <------------------ Error Here
                // Do something
            }
            else
            {
                // Do other things
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although the `data` field is typeof text, but the DB author store binary data inside it, so I want to get back the value as binary data.

I was successfully get `ex_data`, but can't get `data` because:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

If I browse the table in a SQLite Viewer change the `data` field's type to `BLOB`, I can get it ok, but for some reason I don't want to modify the database at all.

I also try:

```
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rdr["data"] as string);
```

which return incorrect data.

**Question:**

How to get `data` text field as binary data?

Comment: Try Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rdr["data"].ToString());

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT typeof(data) FROM fruit WHERE ...`? Is it `text` or `blob`?

Comment: @CL. in the table definition code it is `TEXT` type, so I get the `text` result.

Comment: SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @CL. if the data start with commons character, ie "abc", it return `text`, else return `blob`. I tested it both in my program and in `DB Browser for SQLite`.

Comment: The value's type depends *only* on what type was used when the value was written.

Comment: @CL. `SELECT typeof(data) FROM fruit WHERE fruit_id=10` return `blob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself, though any other work solution are welcome:

Use `GetStream` method:

```
    byte[] h = null;
    using (MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var rs = rdr.GetStream(rdr.GetOrdinal("data")))
        {
            rs.CopyTo(mm);
        }
        h = mm.ToArray();
    }
```